# Why would Pytorch be non-deterministic for batch only?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am training a LSTM network on CPU and can achieve deterministic results when not using a dataloader. But when I used Pytorchs dataloader I achieve non-deterministic training error results, despite the actual batches being loaded from the dataloader being deterministic.

I have set pretty much every seed I could think of here

```
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)

torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False  
torch.backends.cudnn.enabled   = False
```

The two pieces of code are:

```
optimiser = torch.optim.Adam(model_test.parameters(), learning_rate)
set_seed(42)

for t in range(num_epochs):

    for batch_idx, (X_train, y_train) in enumerate(train_loader):

        # Zero out gradients
        optimiser.zero_grad()

        # Forward pass
        y_pred = model_test(X_train)

        # Loss Function
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_train)

        # Backward pass
        loss.backward()

        # Update parameters
        optimiser.step()

    if t % 100 == 0: print("Epoch ", t, "MSE: ", loss.item())
```

and

```
optimiser = torch.optim.Adam(model_test.parameters(), learning_rate)
set_seed(42)

for t in range(num_epochs):

    # Zero out gradients
    optimiser.zero_grad()

    # Forward pass
    y_pred = model_test(X_train)

    # Loss Function
    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_train)

    # Backward pass
    loss.backward()

    # Update parameters
    optimiser.step()

    if t % 100 == 0: print("Epoch ", t, "MSE: ", loss.item())
```

I have seen some posts on Github talking about there being issues with determinism on GPU, but this is just on CPU.

Answer (score 1):

The cudnn implementaton of the LSTM has determinism issues that appear to be fixed in the 7.6.1 release. Check your cudnn version.

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/18110

Answer (score 0):

It can be made deterministic by adding set_seed(42) after optimiser.zero_grad(). Not sure what happens in optimiser.zero_grad() to mess with the seeding on every batch.